Can I use a 13amp 3prong extension cord to plug in my upright freezer?
I bought a 13.3cu feet standing freezer (2.5amp, 115volt) and it does not fit near an existing outlet. I bought a 15 foot extension cord (13amp) to use to power on the appliance.
I was googling and was worried if this is safe or whether this would void by home warranty? Is the type of extension cord ok to use in this situation or do I need to relocate my freezer to my garage (near an outlet).
I’m terrified it will burn my house and my
Insurance won’t cover it. Any help you can give would be much appreciated!

Re the 13 amp cord, do you live in Britain or Europe?

@Triplefault Unlikely. (a) 115V is obsolete but common terminology for US/Canada but not Europe; (b) cheap 16 AWG extension cords are rated 13A example from Home Depot

@Triplefault I live in Ontario Canada

If an extension cord is going to keep you up at night, don't use it!  I think it's not a necessary fear, if you use the right cord the right way and are aware of safe usage guidelines.  On the other hand, it's not a ridiculous fear and its not that hard to avoid so why give yourself grief?

TL;DR It will work fine
Your freezer runs on a 15A or 20A circuit. But it only uses 2.5A, which is much less than 15A and also much less than 13A. It might use a little more when the compressor starts up, but only for a few seconds, which is not a serious concern.
A "home warranty" usually doesn't mean much, and in many cases they will use any excuse to exclude something from coverage. In this case, that would probably not be "13A extension cord" but "any extension cord". Why? Because your freezer instructions probably say "do not use an extension cord".
From a practical standpoint, what matters is why do they say "do not use an extension cord". The main issues are:

Can it handle the load? That is a real issue for some things, but should not be an issue here (2.5A being much smaller than 13A)
Is it safe in other ways? The big ones are: tripping hazard and potential damage to the extension cord. If you run the cord along a wall then there is generally not much of an issue. If you run the cord across the floor then these are both big issues. You have a tripping hazard if the cord is exposed and a hidden damage concern if the cord is covered up.

So if you are using the extension cord in a safe manner then this really not a problem. Moving the freezer to the garage may be a much bigger problem. Ordinary residential refrigerators and freezers are designed to work well in a narrow temperature range - e.g., between 50F and 90F. If you install them in a garage that has wide temperature swings (both cold and hot are concerns) then they may not work properly.

Thank you for answering! I meant to say home insurance not warranty - could the use of an extension cord potentially mean my insurer (TD) may not pay out in the event of a fire?

Interesting question. Hard to say for sure. If the extension cord really was a cause, then of course - that's the "hidden damage" concern.

Point to note: if your garage is routinely colder than your kitchen - which it probably is - then it will run more efficiently, and conversely will help to warm up your garage by about a tenth of a degree.

Do the instructions say you can (or can't) use an extension cord on the freezer? If they say you can't you would be going against the UL listing for the appliance.

@MikeB until it gets too cold in the garage for it to work properly.  For freezers that's pretty cold, but fridge-freezers can be a problem because the fridge doesn't need much cooling so the freezer doesn't get enough.  And the increased efficiency could well be more than offset by all the cold air you let into the house every time you fetch something from the freezer

One other hazard with extension leads on the floor in kitchens and similar areas is water getting into the connection between the appliance lead and the extension

@ChrisH but if it gets too cold for it to work properly, isn't that gonna basically be cold enough for it not to matter?

@Huesmann no. For a fridge freezer, put it at 2 degrees C ambient.  The fridge never needs to run at all but the freezer will eventually defrost. This is especially true of frost-free models (the air circulates coils -> freezer -> fridge). Most models are designed in the expectation that they'll be at room temperature, meaning some heat leaks into the fridge.  Of course they could be built for colder, but they're not.  Dedicated freezers are often better - Beko (manufacturer) spec theirs for -15C

@ChrisH OP says it's an upright freezer though.

@Huesmann as are most sold by Beko, hence why I included the link specifically stating that most freezers aren't designed to work below 10C (including a Beko I used to have)

Every time anyone asks about homeowner insurance refusing to pay a claim because an occupant did something wrong, I ask this, and will ask again now:  can anyone point me to any case of such a thing happening, to a news report of such a thing  happening, or to an actual policy document, legislation, regulation, or ANYTHING supporting this notion that an insurance claim can be denied, has been denied, or ever would be denied because a homeowner, or one of her family or friends or other occupants, did not follow all the instructions of all the appliances in their home?

A single appliance on a 13A lead should be fine.  But if possible, use a higher gauge one.
Motorized appliances, including freezers, can take a large surge of current on start-up.  Much higher than the rating plate would suggest.  If fed by an under-sized extension lead, the voltage at the appliance end of the lead can drop significantly.  This makes it harder for the motor to start, increasing wear on the motor.  In extreme cases, the motor could stall and not start at all.
That's why fridge and freezer manufacturers may void the warranty if you've used an extension lead.

If you want to be extra cautious, you could get a power strip with a 15' cable.
These are often required in commercial situations by fire inspector instead of an extension cord.  And in dorm rooms.
This has an added protection of ensuring your extension cord itself does not draw more than the cord is rated.
It does not have to have a surge protector (which cost more) -- just a power strip.  Also don't get some random non-UL listed one from amazon.  Your local big box hardware store will likely have them (from a more reliable supply chain.)
Apparently not all power strips have circuit breakers.  I've never seen one, but be sure to get one with a circuit breaker.

Is there something different to how power strips work in the US than the UK? in the UK the fuse is in the plug, so an extension cord with a 13A fuse and a powerstrip with a 13A fuse equally protect against exceeding the rated load; the only difference between a basic UK power strip and an extension is that there are more sockets on the strip.

Power strips are not required to be fused in the US so this seems like dangerous advice

@PeteKirkham I'm also UK based with a little experience of US stuff.  Maybe the wire size has to be bigger on a power strip than is allowed on a single extension (that's, at least effectively, the case in the UK where you can buy 10A extension leads with 1 or 2 sockets). The only real difference I can think of is geometry - because pulling on the lead pulls US plugs out, and their trailing single sockets can be similarly in-line, tugging on either end could pull the plug half out (unlike ours with their inherent right angles).  That then leads to poor contact combined with low contact pressure
